# Comparing 8 categories (degree) against % who did a gap year within that degree - which test?

Tags: anova, spss

Want to see if there is a statistically significant difference between the % of students who did a gap year across 8 different degrees.

$$
\begin{array}{l|r}
\text{Degree}  &  \text{Gap } [\%]            \\\hline\\\hline
\text{Architecture}& 8.82 \\\hline
\text{Biology}&                22.41 \\\hline
\text{Languages}&              22.22 \\\hline
\text{Mathematical Sciences}&  4.55 \\\hline
\text{Mechanical Engineering}& 12.43 \\\hline
\text{Pharmacy}&               30.00 \\\hline
\text{Politics}&               37.04 \\\hline
\text{Psychology}&             32.65
\end{array}
$$

Which stats test is used?  Been reading conflicting things online and in my stats book.  Thought a one-way ANOVA would be it, so tried in SPSS but only it recognised one variable (gap %) so wouldn't run the test.

[image: Screenshot of SPSS]

Perhaps the layout is wrong?  Is the cohort categorical and the gap % scale?

Comment: Thanks, in which case I've got my answer as I have already performed a chi-square on the actual numbers, just wasn't sure whether it really was the right test to be using for my question.  Thanks for your help (don't seem to be able to mark this as answered though?).

Comment: I promoted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use a Pearson $X^2$ (chi-squared) test to answer this question, but you will need the actual numbers (not just the proportions); otherwise you're probably completely out of luck.

For a one-way ANOVA (or a rank-based nonparametric analogue like the Kruskal-Wallis test) you would need  repeated samples within each category. The Pearson test (or the very similar $G$ test) avoids this necessity because it is restricted to count data, for which you can assume an implicit relationship between the mean and variance: the number of counts per cell is assumed to be Poisson distributed, which is in turn approximated by a Normal distribution.